# Changing the window.scroll placement based on a media query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The site I'm working on has a "mandatory" Header at the top they won't let me remove. My workaround for this was to start the window scroll below that header with a body onLoad event, like such:

```
    <body <?php body_class(); ?> onLoad="window.scroll(0, 100)">
```

The issue comes up as I'm working on the sites responsive elements. When the screen hits the 400px media query, I hide that div entirely. Which means my site is still scrolling 100px down needlessly.

Is there a way to Change that window.scroll event to NOT scroll down, (or to scroll down less if they make me put the header back on mobile, albeit smaller) based on that media query?

Comment: Do you only need the script to execute when the page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play around with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JaF8M/1/)

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#content").offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

Basically it scrolls to the element you want to show so if the header is not present the #content top will be 0 so it won't scroll.

Alternatively, you could use the code below which will scroll the site accordingly to the header's height. No header = no height = problem solved.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#header").height()
    }, 1000);
});
```